# how to embed a Treeview in List view in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, treeview

How to embed a Treeview structure in the list view? How to change the Listview as below structure

[image: Sample image]

Answer (score 0):

You may start with [WPF TreeListView Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30721/WPF-TreeListView-Control) article. It helped me to achieve that functionality 2 years ago.